# JForg Artifactory 7.12.6 fails to start the access server after restart

Tags: artifactory

I have encountered an issue with our JForg Artifactory v7.12.6

We needed to install our self signed certificate on our servers, added it to the CentOS trust and the java certstore so far so good.

Then restarted the Artifactory. After some investigation of the logs, I saw that the access server doesn't properly start. It terminates with NPE because it can't load a configuration.
So the Artifactory service itself fails to start as it can't reach the access server.

access log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.jfrog.access.server.service.projects.permissions.ProjectPermissionsGenerator.getRolePermissions(ProjectPermissionsGenerator.java:165)
```

Artifactory log:

```
Cluster join: Retry 5: Service registry ping failed, will retry. Error: Error while trying to connect to local router at address 'http://localhost:8046/access': Get "http://localhost:8046/access/api/v1/system/ping": dial tcp [::1]:8046: connect: connection refused [access_client]
```

But the Artifactory wasn't touched since the last update, that was 2 months ago and has been running without an issue.

We use the crowd integration, so our Crowd server was part of the updates, but we rolled back the changes on the Crowd server as we expected that to be the source of the error. But that didn't help. And our other applications that using crowd don't have an issue.

Restoring a backup from the day before failed also.

Then trying to restore older configurations for the access and artifactory service didn't help.

Unfortunately the JFrog support and the knowledgebase isn't helpful.

Thanks in advance for the help.

access-service.log:

```
2021-04-13T10:53:54.512Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [o.j.a.AccessApplication:50    ] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - Starting AccessApplication v7.12.6 on **** with PID 5417 (/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/access-application-7.12.6.jar started by artifactory in /)
2021-04-13T10:53:54.513Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [o.j.a.AccessApplication:652   ] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - The following profiles are active: production
2021-04-13T10:53:54.502Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [                ] [ackson2ObjectMapperBuilder:836] [background-preinit  ] - For Jackson Kotlin classes support please add "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin" to the classpath
2021-04-13T10:54:00.269Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [c.z.h.u.DriverDataSource:70   ] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - Registered driver with driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2021-04-13T10:54:00.338Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [s.d.u.AccessJdbcHelperImpl:140] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - Database: Apache Derby 10.14.2.0 - (1828579). Driver: Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver 10.14.2.0 - (1828579)
2021-04-13T10:54:00.338Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [s.d.u.AccessJdbcHelperImpl:143] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - Connection URL: jdbc:derby:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/artifactory/derby
2021-04-13T10:54:01.527Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [alConfigurationServiceBase:182] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - Loading configuration from db finished successfully
2021-04-13T10:54:01.776Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [alConfigurationServiceBase:114] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - Current configurations are the same as the new configurations, no need for an update. No action was taken.
2021-04-13T10:54:02.282Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [.h.AccessNodeIdProviderImpl:73] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - Service id initialized: jfac@01ct60ccbb5k9n01gg4ax4057y
2021-04-13T10:54:03.091Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [j.a.s.s.t.TokenServiceImpl:115] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - Scheduling task for revoking expired tokens using cron expression: 0 0 0/1 * * ?
2021-04-13T10:54:04.180Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [b.AccessServerBootstrapImpl:43] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Starting JFrog Access bootstrap...
2021-04-13T10:54:04.180Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:121] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Initializing root certificate.
2021-04-13T10:54:05.077Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:342] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Saved new root certificate at: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/access/keys/root.crt
2021-04-13T10:54:05.079Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:138] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Finished initializing root certificate. Certificate source: DATABASE
2021-04-13T10:54:05.079Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:121] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Initializing ca certificate.
2021-04-13T10:54:05.292Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:342] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Saved new ca certificate at: /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/access/keys/ca.crt
2021-04-13T10:54:05.293Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [CertificateFileHandlerBase:138] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - [ACCESS BOOTSTRAP] Finished initializing ca certificate. Certificate source: DATABASE
2021-04-13T10:54:05.828Z [jfac ] [WARN ] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [ebServerApplicationContext:559] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jerseyConfig' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/access-application-7.12.6.jar!/org/jfrog/access/rest/config/JerseyConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.jfrog.access.rest.config.JerseyConfig]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'systemResource' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/access-server-rest-7.12.6.jar!/org/jfrog/access/server/rest/resource/system/SystemResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accessServerBootstrapImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
2021-04-13T10:54:05.945Z [jfac ] [ERROR] [11ee0208fe23ba04] [o.s.b.SpringApplication:823   ] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jerseyConfig' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/access-application-7.12.6.jar!/org/jfrog/access/rest/config/JerseyConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.jfrog.access.rest.config.JerseyConfig]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'systemResource' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/access-server-rest-7.12.6.jar!/org/jfrog/access/server/rest/resource/system/SystemResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accessServerBootstrapImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5144)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1822)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jerseyConfig' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/access-application-7.12.6.jar!/org/jfrog/access/rest/config/JerseyConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.jfrog.access.rest.config.JerseyConfig]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'systemResource' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/access-server-rest-7.12.6.jar!/org/jfrog/access/server/rest/resource/system/SystemResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accessServerBootstrapImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:202)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:96)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:253)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:184)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jerseyConfig' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/access-application-7.12.6.jar!/org/jfrog/access/rest/config/JerseyConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.jfrog.access.rest.config.JerseyConfig]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'systemResource' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/access-server-rest-7.12.6.jar!/org/jfrog/access/server/rest/resource/system/SystemResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accessServerBootstrapImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.jfrog.access.rest.config.JerseyConfig]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'systemResource' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/access-server-rest-7.12.6.jar!/org/jfrog/access/server/rest/resource/system/SystemResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accessServerBootstrapImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:309)
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'systemResource' defined in URL [jar:file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/access/WEB-INF/lib/access-server-rest-7.12.6.jar!/org/jfrog/access/server/rest/resource/system/SystemResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accessServerBootstrapImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1356)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1203)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansWithAnnotation(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:673)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1265)
    at org.jfrog.access.rest.config.JerseyConfig.registerAdditionalResources(JerseyConfig.java:60)
    at org.jfrog.access.rest.config.JerseyConfig.<init>(JerseyConfig.java:38)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:204)
    ... 63 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accessServerBootstrapImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:415)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788)
    ... 81 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.jfrog.access.server.service.projects.permissions.ProjectPermissionsGenerator.getRolePermissions(ProjectPermissionsGenerator.java:165)
    at org.jfrog.access.server.service.projects.permissions.ProjectPermissionsGenerator.lambda$getRolePermissions$2(ProjectPermissionsGenerator.java:81)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1603)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.jfrog.access.server.service.projects.permissions.ProjectPermissionsGenerator.getRolePermissions(ProjectPermissionsGenerator.java:85)
    at org.jfrog.access.server.service.projects.permissions.ProjectPermissionsGenerator.lambda$getRolePermissions$5(ProjectPermissionsGenerator.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.jfrog.access.server.service.projects.permissions.ProjectPermissionsGenerator.getRolePermissions(ProjectPermissionsGenerator.java:121)
    at org.jfrog.access.server.service.projects.permissions.ProjectPermissionServiceImpl.createPermissions(ProjectPermissionServiceImpl.java:47)
    at org.jfrog.access.server.bootstrap.AccessProjectBootstrap.lambda$initPermissions$1(AccessProjectBootstrap.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.jfrog.access.server.bootstrap.AccessProjectBootstrap.initPermissions(AccessProjectBootstrap.java:51)
    at org.jfrog.access.server.bootstrap.AccessProjectBootstrap.init(AccessProjectBootstrap.java:46)
    at org.jfrog.access.server.bootstrap.AccessServerBootstrapImpl.initializeServer(AccessServerBootstrapImpl.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)
    ... 94 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I could kind of solve the issue but I don't exactly know what fixed it. I got some vague ideas.
We hat do reinstall the Artifactory and reimport an old backup. That's where we noticed that it's not a recent issue but it seams to be from a borked version update that we did two months ago.
Artifactory was happily running two months until we restarted it. So all our full backups that we had contain the error.

As far as I can tell it's a corrupted / incompatible access server config. Once a new Artifactory is running and then the backup is imported it will work until the next restart where it loads the configs from the DB.
We used the embedded Derby DB, as we only run a couple apps. So not a big Artifactory.

Once it was more or less clear it's a config that lives in the DB we switched to a external postgres DB. With the idea that it would be easier to debug.
Installed Artifactory on a test server anew now with postgres instead of the embedded DB, checked the config in the DB, made a copy of it.
Imported the backup. Checked the config again and restarted the Artifactory.
To our surprise the error was gone. The access server could load the config without an issue and the Artifactory started. Didn't need to amend the config manually.

So my guess is that the embedded Derby DB isn't a s robust or the import process is different to the process that is used for an external DB.
Either way, we could recover the Artifactory with the borked backup.

For somebody else with the same or similar error the switching to an external DB might help.

Also regularly test that your backups work